# Running Javascript scripts sent via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I don't know much about the ajax and its functionality. I wanted to call a php page from another php page through ajax call but its not working. I just wanted the alert to be displayed which is in the "delete.php" when I press a delete button from the "index.php".

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$host="192.168.20.171";
$user="production";
$password="******";
$database="*****";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>categoryId</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>Operations</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql_query = "select category_id,category from cscart_category_descriptions;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql_query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row["category_id"].'</td><td>'.$row["category"].'</td><td><button class="deletedata" data-id="'.$row['category_id'].'">Del</button></td></tr>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).on('click','.deletedata',function(){
            id = $(this).attr('data-id'); // Get the clicked id for deletion 
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'delete.php',
                data:{delete_id:id},
                success:function(response){
                    if (response == 'ok') {
                            alert("succes");
                    } else {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                }
            })});
        </script>
    </table>
</html>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';
    if($_GET('delete_id'))
    {
        echo"<script>alert('jjjj');</script>";

    }
?>
```

Comment: You are getting any error in firebug?

Comment: Things that you have to note is that. you have to include config.php in dbconnect.php. and include dbconnect.php in your index.php.

Comment: the javascript in `delete.php` will not be executed as you are intending

Comment: You can't really inject a script and have it run on the client side just like that. You need to evaluate the script on the client side in order for the `alert('jjjj')` to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

What you echo in the `delete.php` file is what is returned as `response` of the ajax.

So in this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'delete.php',
    data:{delete_id:id},
    success:function(response){
        if (response == 'ok') {
                alert("succes");
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    }
})});
```

The response is `<script>alert('jjjj');</script>`, which makes your code enter the else and alert `fail`.

What you need to do is echo `ok` in your `delete.php` and then alert `jjjj` on success. That would be:

```
//delete.php
include 'config.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';
if($_GET('delete_id'))
{
    echo "ok";
}
```

Your ajax call would be similar, with the only difference of what you alert on success.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'delete.php',
    data:{delete_id:id},
    success:function(response){
        if (response == 'ok') {
            alert("jjjj");
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    }
})});
```

Usually, when you do ajax calls and get a response, your next actions would depend on the received response, so most often you'll have something like `alert(response)` (or any other action that utilizes what's been received from the server), instead of doing a static alert.

You should consider learning a bit more about AJAX before starting using it.

Comment: How to alert the script of `delete.php`? you have not answered it.

Comment: It's updated, there's only a change in what you alert on success.

Comment: No! Still not answered it.

Comment: check this answer and the demo. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38476157/1059101

Comment: @trajchevska I don't think you are answering the question

Comment: Returning script from server side and appending it to the html is not a good practice. That is why my answer implies that the delete.php script should return the 'ok' message and all the rest should be handled in ajax success. It completely answers the question and includes notes that could benefit both the OP and other users.

Comment: I just wanted the ajax call to be made. Please alerts are only to verify that i made the ajax call to the delete.php. So, please answer point to point.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a `GET` request to `delete.php`, you can have that `script` from that php to your current script but you have to append it:

```
success:function(response){
    // here response is the script tag from delete.php
    $(document.head).append(response);
}
```

### [A plnkr DEMO in action.](https://plnkr.co/edit/NtxTg8L4XzqysD9xU798?p=preview)

Comment: This answers the question properly.

Answer (score -1):

//delete.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'dbconnect.php';

echo 'ok';

?>
```

whatever you echo in php page will get back to you in ajax response.